# Device shown using lspci but udev not loading the driver

Tags: networking, drivers, udev

My nic shows using lspci -v but udev is not loading the driver for it. 
Links to screenshots of diagnostic output are below.

[dmesg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp6axzrdcrlkrxw/dmesg.PNG?dl=0)

[insmod](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ropy3owp8xc03xn/insmod.PNG?dl=0)

[lspci](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bwxvgl8m8u7fv2/lspci.PNG?dl=0)

[pacman -Qi](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i15fi37m6uq8eu1/pacman%20-Qi%20linux.PNG?dl=0)

[ls /sys/class/net](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7d5tnl3gby8gci9/sys-class-net.PNG?dl=0)

[uname -a](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o04qhfeh5tq47ag/uname%20-a.PNG?dl=0)

[original thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199442)

More info (manually typed and not copied and pasted from the vm):

```
find /usr/lib/`uname -r`/kernel -iname "mii*"
/lib/modules/4.0.1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/mii.ko.gz


modprobe pcnet32
echo $?
1

modprobe -v --dryrun pcnet32
echo $?
1
```

There was nothing relevant in dmesg after using modprobe. So I tried using insmod on mii and pcnet32. It detected the nics on the machine. So the question now becomes why does modprobe not work?

Comment: Run `insmod` for *pcnet32* and check output of `dmesg`. There should be cause of `insmod` failure.

Comment: see the dmesg and insmod screenshots.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't use images for posting textual problem. It's difficult for [Google](https://www.google.pl/) (and [other search engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines)) to index problems described by images. However, if you really need posting images, you should upload your images [this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: @patryk.beza: it's in a vm. I can't copy and paste from it. Original question was posted on arch forums hence the offsite links.

Comment: You [can](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73059/how-to-copy-paste-from-ubuntu-virtualbox-guest-to-windows-host).

Comment: Should have said I don't have X, so no clipboard, no mouse etc..

Comment: OK, fine, see comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From `insmod` manpage:

> insmod is a trivial program to insert a module into the kernel. Most users will want to use **modprobe**(8) instead, which is more clever and can handle module dependencies.

`pcnet32` module depends on `mii` module, which is not loaded when you load `pcnet32` using `insmod`.

`modprobe pcnet32` should solve the problem.

Alternatively you can use `insmod` for `mii` module and then `insmod` for `pcnet32`, but keep in mind that if `mii` depends on other module, then you will have still similar problem as you posted above.

Comment: no modprobe doesn't help

Comment: Can you post result of the two commands: `modprobe pcnet32` and `find /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/kernel/drivers/net/ -name "mii*"`? I reproduced your error and my solution worked for me.

Comment: update original question.

Comment: OK, now `insmod mii && insmod pcnet32` works for you and `modprobe pcnet32` doesn't. Post result of: `modprobe --dry-run -v pcnet32`.